# What's the difference between str and String::from in this example?

Tags: rust

What's the difference between str and String::from in this example

```
use std::borrow::Cow;


fn main() {

    let s = "Hello world!";
    
    let cow: Cow<str> = Cow::Owned(s);
    // type mismatch resolving `<str as std::borrow::ToOwned>::Owned == &str`
    //expected struct `std::string::String`, found `&str`
    
    // ok
    let cow: Cow<str> = Cow::Owned(String::from(s)); 
    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Cow::Owned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) takes as input the associated type `Owned` of the generic parameter (which must implement [`ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html)). For `str`, [this is `String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#impl-ToOwned). Therefore, `s` itself cannot be used in `Cow::Owned(s)`.